# (DOORS/DXL) Export to pdf or print with a given template

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, report, ibm-doors

We are interested in export/print one view from formal module. As we want it can be an ofcial document we want to add our corporative template that have it own front page, and its own headers and footers pages with a given text font, size, and color, and inserted images (company symbol, clients ones).

As far as I can see, DOORS let us print adding header&footer but without images. On the other side it is possible export to Word adding a template, but I can't do it directly to pdf format or to a printer.

It is important for us that a corporative document can be directly made by doors without Word or any other editor management in order DOORS document could be directly released to clients without external changes.

Is it possible made it by a DXL script? Or there is any other option to make it?

I suppose that many users have to print (or make pdf files) using their company corporative images, and I think this can be so useful.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible made it by a DXL script?

IMHO it is. I already wrote a DXL script to export DOORS modules to a LaTeX file which can be compiled into a PDF. You will find it at the end of this answer. Feel free to adapt it to your needs. Before you can run it you need to download the source of "[Smart Folder Browser](http://www.smartdxl.com/content/?p=618)" and store it besides my script as "smartFolderBrowser.inc". Die extension inc indicates that this is an include file and not a standalone DXl program.

Of course every user which wants to use such an approach needs an installed TeX distribution like [MiKTeX](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=miktex&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://miktex.org/&ei=-K6bUJnTKofwsgbRlIDQCg&usg=AFQjCNHgQLBEuvR17QqYsxZtVJPBrk0-IA). The DXL script could start the PDF build after the export with the DXL built-in function `void system(string command)`.

With your custom DXL LaTeX export script you will have to full control over the layout of the resulting PDF. But be aware of the layout rules which TeX applies. It can be a very challenging task to configure (force) TeX to render a document as it has been created with M$ Word.

```
// DOORS LaTeX Export
/**
Copyright (c) 2012-2013 Kai K.

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a
copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
"Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included
in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS
OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
*/
pragma encoding, "UTF-8"


#include "smartFolderBrowser.inc"

DBE dbeOutputFolder = null;
DBE dbeOptions = null;
bool withTitles = true
Buffer tempBuf = create;

void escapeSpecialLaTeXCharacters(Buffer& str)
{
   Buffer temp = create;

   int i = 0;
   for(i = 0; i < length(str); ++i) 
   {
      char c = str[i]; 
      if( '\\' == c ) 
      {
         temp += "\\textbackslash{}";
      }
      else if( '{' == c )
      {
         temp += "\\"
         temp += c
      }
      else if( '}' == c )
      {
         temp += "\\"
         temp += c
      }
      else if( '_' == c )
      {
         temp += "\\"
         temp += c
      }
      else if( '^' == c )
      {
         temp += "\\textasciicircum{}";
      }
      else if( '#' == c )
      {
         temp += "\\"
         temp += c
      }
      else if( '&' == c )
      {
         temp += "\\"
         temp += c
      }
      else if( '$' == c )
      {
         temp += "\\"
         temp += c
      }
      else if( '%' == c )
      {
         temp += "\\"
         temp += c
      }
      else if( '~' == c )
      {
         temp += "\\textasciitilde{}";
      }
      else
      {
         temp += c;
      }
   }

   str = tempStringOf(temp);
   delete temp;
}

string makeLabel(Buffer& str)
{
   setempty(tempBuf);

   int i = 0;
   for(i = 0; i < length(str); ++i) 
   {
      char c = str[i]; 
      if( ' ' != c && '-' != c && '\n' != c && '\\' != c && '_' != c && '#' != c) 
      {
         tempBuf += c;
      }
   }
   return stringOf(tempBuf);
}

string makeCaption(Buffer& str)
{
   setempty(tempBuf);

   int i = 0;
   for(i = 0; i < length(str); ++i) 
   {
      char c = str[i]; 
      if( '\n' != c && '\\' != c) 
      {
         tempBuf += c;
      }
   }
   escapeSpecialLaTeXCharacters(tempBuf);
   return stringOf(tempBuf);
}

void rtf2latex(Buffer& buf)
{
   Buffer txt = create;
   Buffer temp = create;
   RichTextParagraph rp = null;
   bool envopened = false;
   for rp in tempStringOf(buf) do {
      if(rp.indentLevel > 0)
      {
         real hspace = realOf(rp.indentLevel)/20.0;
         temp += "{\\hangindent" hspace "pt\\hangafter0"
      }
      if(rp.isBullet)
      {
         temp += "\\textbullet ";
      }      
      RichText rt = null      
      for rt in rp do {
         txt = rt.text;         
            escapeSpecialLaTeXCharacters(txt);

         if (rt.italic)
         {
            temp += "\\textit{";
            temp += txt;
            temp += "}";
         }
         else if (rt.bold)
         {
            temp += "\\textbf{";
            temp += txt;
            temp += "}";
         }
         else if (rt.strikethru)
         {
            temp += "\\sout{";
            temp += txt;
            temp += "}";
         }
         else if (rt.subscript)
         {
            temp += "\\textsubscript{";
            temp += txt;
            temp += "}";
         }
         else if (rt.superscript)
         {
            temp += "\\textsuperscript{";
            temp += txt;
            temp += "}";
         }
         else if (rt.underline)
         {
            temp += "\\underline{";
            temp += txt;
            temp += "}";
         }         
         else
         {
            temp += txt;
         }
         if (rt.newline && !rt.last)
         {
            temp += "\\par\n";
         }
         else if(rt.last)
         {
            temp += "\n";
         }
      }
      if(rp.indentLevel > 0)
      {
         temp += "}"
      }
   }
   buf = tempStringOf(temp);
   delete temp;
   delete txt;  
}

void getObjectText(Object obj, Buffer& buf)
{  
   if(!null(obj))
   {
      buf = richTextFragment(richText(obj."Object Text"));
      rtf2latex(buf);
   }
   else
   {
      buf = "null";
      print("ERROR: obj null!: "dxlHere() "\n");
   }   
}

int nextCell(Stream& oss, int curCol, int numCols )
{
   if( curCol == numCols )
   {
      oss << "\\\\\n\\hline\n"
   }
   else
   {
      oss << "\t&\t"
   }

   return( curCol % numCols + 1 )
}

void writePreamble(Stream& oss)
{
   oss << "\\documentclass[a4paper]{book}\n";
   oss << "%---- packages ----\n";
   oss << "\\usepackage{ulem}\n";
   oss << "\\usepackage{color}\n";
   oss << "\\usepackage{graphicx}\n";
   oss << "\\usepackage{supertabular}\n";
   oss << "\\usepackage{hyperref}\n";
   oss << "\\usepackage{makeidx}\n";
   oss << "\\usepackage{xltxtra}\n";
   oss << "\\makeindex\n";
   oss << "%\n---- settings ----\n";
   oss << "\\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}\n";
   oss << "\\setlength{\\parindent}{0}\n";
   oss << "\\setlength{\\parskip}{2x}\n";
   oss << "%\n---- customizations ----\n";
   oss << "\\makeatletter\n";
   oss << "\\def\\maxwidth{%\n";
   oss << "\\ifdim\\Gin@nat@width>\\linewidth\n";
   oss << "\\linewidth\n";
   oss << "\\else\n";
   oss << "\\Gin@nat@width\n";
   oss << "\\fi\n";
   oss << "}\n";
   oss << "\\makeatother\n";
   oss << "\n%---- document ----\n";
   oss << "\\begin{document}\n";
   oss << "\\tableofcontents\n";
   oss << "\\listoffigures\n";
   oss << "\\listoftables\n";
}

void writeTableHeader(Stream& oss, Object tableobj, int& numCols )
{
   //print("Enter: writeTableHeader\n");
   numCols = 0
   int numRows = 0;
   int tableWidth = 0;

   Object cellobj = null;
   Object rowobj = null;
   // first count the columns and rows
   for rowobj in table( tableobj ) do {
      if( !isDeleted( rowobj ) )
      {
         if(numCols == 0)
         {
            for cellobj in rowobj do {
               if( !isDeleted( cellobj ))
               {
                  tableWidth += getCellWidth(cellobj);
                  numCols++;              
               }
            }
         }
         numRows++;
      }
   }

   // extract the header row
   int colCount = numCols;
   int col = 0;   
   Object headrow[colCount];
   for rowobj in table( tableobj ) do {
      if( !isDeleted( rowobj ) )
      {
         if(col == 0)
         {
            for cellobj in rowobj do {
               if( !isDeleted( cellobj ))
               {
                  headrow[col] = cellobj;
                  col++;
               }
            }
         }
         else
         {            
            break;
         }
      }
   }

   // export the table head
   oss << "\\begin{centering}\n";

   Buffer buf = create;
   oss << "\\tablefirsthead{";   
   for(col=0; col<colCount; ++col) {
      getObjectText(headrow[col], buf);
      oss << tempStringOf(buf);
      if(col+1<colCount)
         oss << "&";
   }
   oss << "\\\\}\n";

   oss << "\\tablehead{";
   for(col=0; col<colCount; ++col) {   
      getObjectText(headrow[col], buf);
      oss << tempStringOf(buf);
      if(col+1<colCount)
         oss << "&";         
   }
   oss << "\\\\}\n";
   oss << "\\tabletail{\\hline}\n";   

   oss << "\\begin{supertabular}{|";
   for(col=0; col<colCount; ++col) {
      cellobj = headrow[col];
      int w = getCellWidth(cellobj);
      real rw = w;
      real tw = tableWidth;
      w = intOf(rw/tw*100.0);
      rw = realOf(w)/100.0;
      oss << "p{" rw "\\textwidth}|";
   }  
   oss << "}\n\\hline\n"

   delete buf;

   //print("Leave: writeTableHeader\n");
}

void writeTableFooter(Stream& oss, Buffer& objtext)
{
   oss << "\\\\\n\\hline\n"
   oss << "\\end{supertabular}\n\\label{tab:";
   oss << makeLabel( objtext );
   oss << "}\n\\bottomcaption{"
   oss << makeCaption( objtext );
   oss << "}\n\\end{centering}\n"
}

void writeobjheading(Stream& oss, Buffer &objNum, Buffer &text, int level )
{
   if(1 == level)
   {
      oss << "\\chapter{";
   }
   else if(2 == level)
   {
      oss << "\\section{";        
   }
   else if(3 == level)
   {
      oss << "\\subsection{";        
   }
   else if(4 == level)
   {
      oss << "\\subsubsection{";        
   }
   else if(5 == level)
   {
      oss << "\\paragraph{";        
   }
   else
   {
      oss << "\\subparagraph{";        
   }

   oss << tempStringOf(text);
   oss << "}\n\\label{sec:";
   oss << makeLabel(text);
   oss << makeLabel(objNum);
   oss << "}\n";
}

void writeFigureHeadAndExport(Stream& oss, Object img, string outputDir)
{
   Module mod = module(img);   
   string n = mod."Prefix"img."Absolute Number"".png";
   string s = exportPicture(img, outputDir "\\" n, formatPNG);   
   oss << "\\begin{figure}[ht]\n";
   oss << "\\centering\n";
   oss << "\\includegraphics[width=\\textwidth]{"n"}\n";
}

void writeFigureFooter(Stream& oss, Buffer& objtext)
{
   oss << "\\label{fig:";
   oss << makeLabel( objtext );
   oss << "}\n\\caption{"
   oss << makeCaption( objtext );
   oss << "}\n\\end{figure}\n";
}

void writeRequirement(Stream& oss, Module& doorsModule, Object obj, Buffer& puid, Buffer& objtext)
{
   oss << "\\textbf{";
   oss << tempStringOf( puid );
   oss << "}\\\\\n" //"PUID style"
   oss << "\\label{req:";
   oss << makeLabel(puid)
   oss << "}\n";
   oss << "\\index{";
   oss << tempStringOf( puid );
   oss << "}\n";
   oss << "\\color{blue}\n"
   oss << tempStringOf( objtext )
   oss << "\n"//"requirement style"

   oss << "\\begin{tabbing}\n"
   Column col = null;
   Buffer var_name = create;
   int c=0;   
   for col in doorsModule do {      
      var_name = title( col )
      escapeSpecialLaTeXCharacters(var_name);

      if( ! main( col ) && search( regexp "(P|p)(U|u)(I|i)(D|d)", var_name, 0 ) == false )
      {         
         oss << "\\textbf{";
         oss << var_name;
         if(c == 0)
            oss <<  "}: \\hspace{2.0cm} \\= "
         else
            oss <<  "}: \\> "

         var_name = text( col, obj );
         escapeSpecialLaTeXCharacters(var_name);
         oss << var_name;
         oss << "\\\\\n";// "attribute valueBuf" )
         c++;
      }               
   }
   oss << "\\end{tabbing}\n"
   oss << "\\color{black}\n"
   delete var_name;
}

void timeString( int timeInSeconds, Buffer &t )
{
   t = ""

   int hours, minutes, seconds

   hours    =   timeInSeconds / 3600
   minutes  = ( timeInSeconds - hours * 3600 ) / 60
   seconds  = ( timeInSeconds - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60 )

   if( hours < 10 ) t = "0"
   t += ( hours "")
   t += ":"
   if( minutes < 10 ) t += "0"
   t += ( minutes "")
   t += ":"
   if( seconds < 10 ) t += "0"
   t += ( seconds "")
}

void doExport(DB db)
{
   int startTime = intOf( today )

   int progressLimit = 0;
   Object obj = null;
   for obj in current Module do {
      progressLimit++;
   }

   progressStart(db, "Exporting Module as LaTeX", "Object 0/"progressLimit"", progressLimit);
   string outputDir = get(dbeOutputFolder);
   string outputFileName = name(current Module);
   string outputFileExt = ".tex";
   string outputFilePath = outputDir "\\" outputFileName outputFileExt;

   Stream mainFile = write(outputFilePath);
   Stream oss = mainFile;

   writePreamble(oss);

   int progress = 1;
   int curCol = 1;
   int numCols = 0;
   bool lastObjWasFigure = false;
   bool lastObjWasTable = false;

   Buffer objheading = create;
   Buffer objtext = create;
   Buffer objNum = create;
   Buffer puid = create;

   int lev = 0
   int puidLevel = 0
   Regexp excel = regexp "objclass Excel.Sheet"
   Module doorsModule = current Module;
   int subfileCount = 1;
   for obj in current Module do {
      if(progressCancelled())
      {
         if( confirm(db, "Do you really want to abort the export?") )
         {
            break;
         }
      }

      progressMessage("Object "progress"/"progressLimit"");

      getObjectText(obj, objtext)

      // ------------------- Handle Tables ------------------------------------
      if( cell( obj ))
      {
         if( !lastObjWasTable )
         {
            writeTableHeader(oss, obj, numCols);            
            curCol           = 1;
            lastObjWasTable  = true;
         }
         else
         {
            curCol = nextCell(oss, curCol, numCols );
         }
         oss << tempStringOf( objtext ); // "Standard"
         progressStep(progress);
         progress++;
         continue
      }

      // ------------------- After Table write Table Title -----------------
      if( lastObjWasTable )
      {
         writeTableFooter(oss, objtext);
      }
      // ------------------- After Figure write Figure Title ---------------
      if( lastObjWasFigure )
      {
         writeFigureFooter(oss, objtext)
      }

      objNum  = number( obj )
      objheading = obj."Object Heading"
      escapeSpecialLaTeXCharacters(objheading)

      // ------------------- Handle End of Requirement ------------------------
      lev = level( obj )
      if( lev <= puidLevel )
      {
         //oss << "End Requirement\n\n"
         puidLevel = 0
      }

      if( withTitles && ( lastObjWasTable || lastObjWasFigure ))
      {
         lastObjWasTable  = false
         lastObjWasFigure = false
         continue
      }

      // ------------------- Handle objheading with hierarchy --------------------
      if( length( objheading ) > 0 )
      {
         writeobjheading(oss, objNum, objheading, lev )
      }

      if( length( objtext ) > 0 )
      {
         // remember, if Title has to be written after this object
         if( containsOle( obj."Object Text"))
         {
            if( excel objtext ) {
               lastObjWasTable = true
            }
            else
            {
               lastObjWasFigure = true;
               writeFigureHeadAndExport(oss, obj, outputDir);
            }
         }
         // ------------------- Handle Requirements objects Text -----------
         puid = obj."IE PUID"
         escapeSpecialLaTeXCharacters(puid)
         if( length( puid ) > 0 )
         {
            puidLevel = lev
            writeRequirement(oss, doorsModule, obj, puid, objtext);
         }
         // ------------------- No PUID means normal text Object -----------
         else
         {
            oss << tempStringOf( objtext );
            oss << "\n";// "Standard"
         }
      }


      progressStep(progress);
      progress++;      
   }

   oss << "\\printindex\n"
   oss << "\\end{document}\n";

   close(oss);
   progressStop();

   // ---------------------- show the result ----------------------------------
   int endTime = intOf( today ) - startTime

   Buffer totalTime = create;
   timeString( endTime, totalTime );

   infoBox( "Export successfully finished after " totalTime "\nThe result is located in\n" outputFilePath);

   delete objheading;
   delete objtext;
   delete objNum;
   delete puid;
   delete tempBuf;
}

DB db = create("LaTeX Export");
dbeOutputFolder = smartFolderBrowser(db, "Output Folder:", false);

ok(db, doExport);
show(db);
```

Comment: Greetings. Thank you for your answer. I will start to find out something about MikTeX. It is new for me so I'm going to check it in order to see whether I can use it. As I'm not a dxl programmer I'm not sure about it.

Comment: I have dowonloaded MikTeX. As far as I understand you, I need your DXL script to export a LaTeX file, I'm revising all questions with dxl tag but I haven't found it. Regarding to prepare a custom DXL to get a personalized cover and headers/footers pages with images, could you give me more details? I'm a newbie and I haven't much idea about programing at dxl. Thank you!!

Comment: @Jose: Of course you didn't find it. I never published the code. I will see if I can upload the code somewhere and share the link here. But this could take a while... Until then I recommend you start reading the DXL reference provided by DOORS.

Comment: Thank you! However when I try to run it an error it is shown: _italic_ **bold** `-E- DXL: <Line:27> could not open include file (utils/smartFolderBrowser.inc) (No such file or directory)`

Comment: @Jose: I added a note about the include file and fixed two script errors. I'm looking forward to get my answer accepted.

Comment: I have saved smartFolderBrowser.inc, and after that I run dxl. The following message is shown `-R-E- DXL: <Line:508> null dialog element (DBE) parameter was passed into argument position 1
`. There isn't any file saved at folder specified son I don't know what I should do now. Please forgive me for give you some troubles with this.

Comment: @Jose: Now I'm remembered why it is good practise to test code before sharing it. I removed the erroneous line(s) and disabled some debug output. But I recommend you learn to debug and write DXL scripts. These skills are essential to adapt the script to your needs. May be you have to hire some DOORS/DXL consultants to assist you.

Comment: Coming late to the party:  I get error " unknown object IE PUID"  at line 611, `puid = obj."IE PUID"  .  DOORS 9.3

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Change the property access as you like. We used "IE PUID" property as human readable requirement ID. Change it to obj."<your_id_prop>"

Comment: @KaiK.  Thanks - -in fact that's what I did after some advice here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39206498/how-to-find-and-export-the-doors-id-value

Comment: Hey @JoseManuelMorenoRamos, after 8 years and 5 upvotes you could accept my answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of DOORS are you using?

In DOORS 9.3+ IBM incorporated functions of RPE into DOORS which allows you more options for exporting, including to export to PDF. However, it wasn't until DOORS 9.4.0.1 (current release) that you could build your own template in IBM Rational Publishing Engine (RPE) and use that template inside of DOORS Directly.

So the answer is that you would need one license for RPE Full from IBM so that you can create the template you are looking for, then anyone that uses DOORS in your company could export DOORS documents using that template, without additional licenses. You also need to be on DOORS 9.4.0.1.

I have also seen some companies export to Word with their headers and footers, then use Adobe Acrobat to add in their cover pages with logos and such. However this means that only people with the full license for Acrobat can generate the documents correctly.

RPE is definitely your best bet.

Comment: As far as I remember we have Doors 9.3... so I assume I can't solve this...

I´ll try to confirm it

Thank you!!

Comment: I am sure that it could be done with DXL, somehow. But by the time the script was written you could be upgraded to 9.4.0.1. It wouldn't be worth the effort.

Comment: I have confirmed we have installed 9.3 Version. I'm not sure we are going to update to 9.4. As you say, our way is export to Word, and after that use Adobe Acrobat. We have all their licenses. However I wanted to avoid these intermediate steps in order to avoid somebody could modify the report. So I thought the best way was print directly with our own cover and page format. Thank you anyway for your help. We should continue using Word as intermediate step to print Doors report altough it can be easily modified.