# How to find and export the DOORS ID value?

Tags: ibm-doors

I found a script to [export to LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266029/doors-dxl-export-to-pdf-or-print-with-a-given-template/13289643#13289643), but at least with the module and DOORS installation at my company (DOORS9.6 via a remote server) , I get an error when trying to execute. The error occurs at the line

```
 // ------------------- Handle Requirements objects Text -----------
         puid = obj."IE PUID"
```

The error message is

> -R-E- DXL:  unknown Object attribute (IE PUID)

If I comment out that line, the script runs w/o error and exports a LaTeX source file.  Problem is, of course, that I need the text of each Object's  DOORS ID,  known as "Object Identifier".  Is there an alternative way to get the info, or is there a different attribute name I could use?  (I don't have a reference doc. with any sort of id -namelists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is, which attribute(s) you need to be exported.

the script you found will export all objects and attributes of the current view to latex, but it is adopted to the needs of the script's author, e.g. “IE PUID” is not a standard DOORS attribute. Thus, you will have to make some changes until the script provides the output you need.

As for the ID, the usual way to address DOORS objects is by using the attribute „Absolute Number“, which is unique for each object in a module. You might want to use this attribute as ID, but perhaps you have a different kind of ID in your modules - I suggest to open the module that you want to export and look at the details (properties) of one object (right mouse button). When you look at the attributes, you should find which attribute is the best “ID” for you.

One other line you will probably need to change is “if( ! main( col ) && search( regexp "(P|p)(U|u)(I|i)(D|d)", var_name, 0 ) == false )”. This line ensures that only columns are exported that do not contain the characters puid or PUID, probably for avoiding that the ID is printed twice. Adopt this to your need as well.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi,  What I need (and am not getting) is the column **Object Identifier**  values.  That is - I commented out the "puid" lines in the original DXL file, and get the other columns' text exported, but not the ID. Something else is rejecting that column's data.  If "absolute number" is in there, it's not getting exported either.

Comment: I seem to have found it: the "attribute" text has to match the ColumnName as displayed.  Changing that string and changing the `regex` to match seems to have done the trick.