# DXL script producing syntax error with char c = str[i]

Tags: ibm-doors

I'm currently trying to run [Export to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266029/doors-dxl-export-to-pdf-or-print-with-a-given-template) script, however when I try running it in DOORS ver 9.6.1, I get a couple of errors.

Line 8: char c = str[i]; contains a syntax error

Any thoughts on how I can resolve this issue?

```
string makeCaption(Buffer& str)
{
   setempty(tempBuf);

   int i = 0;
   {
   for(i = 0; i < length(str); ++i) 
      char c = str[i];
      if('\n' != c) && '\\' != c)
      {
         tempBuf += c;
      }
   }
   escapeSpecialLaTeXCharacters(tempBuf);
   return stringOf(tempBuf);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like copy/paste problems. When you compare your code with the original you might notice that you moved line 6 with the sole { one line up. If you put it back where it belongs i.e. after the line "for(...)", the code works